# Why is my .NET MongoDb Driver Query Horribly Slow?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I run a query to `select all items where field1=x, field2 =y, and field3=z` directly in Mongo (Robomongo, CLI, whatever) and it takes less than a second on several hundred thousand items:

```
db.items.find( { 
    $and: [ 
        { CreatingOrgId: 1 }, 
        { LocationId: 941 },
        { StatusId: 1}
    ] 
} )
```

I then try to run the exact same thing from C# driver and it lags out(only "Aggregate filter" code is relevant, everything else is for context):

```
FilterDefinition<BsonDocument> locationsFilter;  = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("LocationId", 941);
FilterDefinition<BsonDocument> orgFilter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("CreatingOrgId", 1);
FilterDefinition<BsonDocument> statusFilter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("StatusId", 1);

FilterDefinition<BsonDocument> aggregateFilter = locationsFilter & statusFilter & orgFilter;

        List<ItemViewModel> stuffList = mongoItemsCollection
                                             .Find(aggregateFilter)
                                             .Project(x => Mapper.Map<BsonDocument, StuffViewModel>(x))
                                             .ToListAsync().Result;
```

What's my mistake here? Here are the queries as mongo sees them:

[image]

Edit: Looks like mapping the items to item object is what's killing my query to some degree. It's fairly fast (couple of seconds for a huge number of records) without the mapping, like so:

```
    var rawItems = mongoItemsCollection
                             .Find(aggregateFilter)
                             .ToListAsync().Result;
```

Edit 2: Looks like automapper is a HUGE part of the problem here (taking the bson "item" object and converting it to a .NET view model). I am still interested in optimization of the .NET --> mongo query itself though (ignoring the automapper part), if anyone wants to answer.

Comment: Side note: using the `$and` is totally unnecessary: `db.items.find({CreatingOrgId: 1, LocationId: 941,  StatusId: 1})`. From what I can see, the order of fields is different between those queries. Assuming you have an index: [Order matters](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/create-indexes-to-support-queries/#create-compound-indexes-to-support-several-different-queries). So you should reorder your filters according to the order of your index.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In practice, I actually have to filter by 5 fields, all of them optional. So things like ABCDE, A, BCD, CDE, D, etc. I am so curious about the details, because I don't understand if an index on ABCDE can handle searching in fields CD, for example. Or whether I would need an index on every possible combination. Though, if I am understanding your link correctly, the example very clearly says that an index on ABCDE will handle all of the subqueries (e.g. the aforementioned 'CD'), as long as they are in order. Also, is there a situation where $and IS necessary?

Comment: Your C# code is doing a ToListAsync so it's accessing all results & returning them. A more equivalent test to compare on CLI would be `.find().toArray() ` otherwise it's only accessing and returning 20 results (by default). If the result set is "several hundred thousand items" that's a big difference especially if the results are not index-only and must be retrieved from disk.

Comment: Looks like the mapping is part of what's killing it, you have a point, will update question.

Comment: @sheilak Can you elaborate on your answer please? My controller is not async, which is why I use .Result() - .toArrayAsync() is not an option when I look at the methods list. I am using C# Driver 2.0.

Comment: How large is the result set of your query? Is it significantly larger than 20? On the CLI are you  only pulling back 20 results? Also, is the query covered by the indexes or does it also need to go to disk?

Comment: @sheilak: The query is fully covered by index now. On CLI, I am pulling 50 results at a time. On the server, I am trying to get a list of up to 5000 results. This would be the source of the problem?

Comment: If it's really fully covered by the index, there wouldn't be a huge difference between 50&5000. If disk is accessed, there could be a bigger difference especially if it's a large collection. Are you sure it's fully covered, including the projected fields returned,  e.g. if you run the query on CLI followed by `.explain("executionStats") ` is `totalDocsExamined` 0? (assuming you are on mongo 3.0)

Comment: @sheilak: Hey, sorry for the slow reply - I was looking for totalDocsExamined, but I am not seeing it anywhere when I run explain or explain("executionStas"). i essentially get the same thing as from running db.system.profile.find({}).limit(10).sort( { ts : -1 } ).pretty(). Btw, if you want to post a reply, I will likely accept it regardless because you have been very helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you run `.ToListAsync()` in C# the entire results of the query are being accessed and returned.

Whereas when you run `.find()` on the command line only 20 (by default) are returned.

A more equivalent test on the command line would be `.find().toArray()` which will also access and return all results. Or you could put a limit in your C# query.

If your full result set is a lot larger than the shell batch size, this could account for some of the difference in your results. This difference will be worse if the query is not covered (i.e. the all the fields in the query and all the fields returned are not in the same index) and if the data accessed is not in memory but is accessed from disk.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you've got an index on the 3 fields, then the problem is that the order of the fields is different between the mongo and the C# query.

The C# query is: LocationId, StatusId, CreatingOrgId

The Mongo query is: CreatingOrgId, LocationId, StatusId

You can validate the exact query in MongoDB by first enabling profiling:

```
db.setProfilingLevel(2); // Profiles all queries.
```

Then, finding the exact query by using:

```
db.system.profile.findOne();
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies on both. I am going to let the bounties run for a bit, but I really appreciate the answer on the generic Q about this. Made it after this iirc because I realized I will need to understand for later and was surprised it wasn't asked already. Edit: I have profiling enabled - that's how I got the screenshot. I think there is also some way to profile from .NET directly, but I couldn't find how to do that easily, though we have some replies on it here which overcomplicate it (I think).